# Set Image position after animation

Tags: android, image, animation

Hi I am applied animation on image.
When animation is finish image is set on it intial position.
But I want its position on last position of animation..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, what code do you use? What exact animation do you use? What about animation listeners?

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I got solution using  animation.setFillAfter(true).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got solution using

> animation.setFillAfter(true).

Comment: I tried same but not working for me here is y code <translate android:duration="1300" android:fillAfter="true" android:fromYDelta="650%" > </translate> Is there any mistake or any thing else please help

Comment: to move my pic from one place to another vertically. Image is moving perfect as I need, but not set at the place where animation ends

Comment: You have to [read this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) first. value must be less than of 100%